# startActivityForResult() does not work

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a button in `Claims.java`. When `button` is pressed, it will show `Alert Dialog Window` with `radio buttons`.If the `radio button` is checked, it will goes to specific activity. In the activity, it has an `editText` and a `save` button. I want the value on the editText display on the  `button`(Claims.java) when the `save` button in the activity is clicked.

Claims.java `>>` AlertDialog Window in Claims.java `>>` AlertDialogRadio.java

I use **startActivityForResult()** to receive a result back from `AlertRadioDialog.java`. But the problem now is it will display `AlertDialogRadio` which is not what I want and the text does not display on the `textView`. How can I do to achieve this?

**Claims.java**

```
 public class Claims extends Fragment {
    private TextView c;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claims, container, false);


        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialogRadio();

            }
        };
        Button button1 = (Button) claims.findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button = (Button) claims.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
         c=(TextView)claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CameraMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return claims;
    }

    public void AlertDialogRadio() {
        final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"Project", "Petrol", "Car Maintenance"
                , "Medical", "Other"};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Claims");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                .OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Petrol.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CarMainten.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Medical.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (item == 4) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Other.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();


    }
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("text");
                c.setText(result);


            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }//onActivityResult
}
```

Assume the user choose Project.

**Project1.java**

```
  public class Project1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String text;
    private static EditText txt;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);
       txt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                text = txt.getText().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're not using `startActivityForResult` at all.

Here's how you should proceed:

**Claims.java**

```
public static final int PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
public static .....
if (item == 0) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Project1.class);
     startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
}
else if .....
```

And in `OnActivityResult` :

```
if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
...
}
else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
...
}
else if ...
```

Comment: Will it return to Claims.java instead of  AlertDialog Window in Claims.java?

Comment: Yes that's how it works. Once you call finish() in the target activity, the execution flows goes to the OnActivityResult() method of the caller activity.

Comment: But it still display the AlertDialog Window ...What should I do so that it will ignore the  AlertDialogRadio() ???

Comment: You are calling the dialog in onCreateView. Its normal to display dialog everytime you show this view. Change your logic when to show Dialog

Comment: but the call to 'startActivityForResult' requires the dialog to be shown. As @X3Btel said, work on the logic.

Comment: Does it has another way to do this?

Comment: I believe that you can solve this on your own. Now that you have a clear perspective on how does startActivityForResult work, it's up to you to 'come up' with the appropriate logic for your app. Happy coding.

Comment: can I put a dialog.dismiss() ?

Comment: it would be much faster if you try, not ask us

Comment: You're welcome. Just try to do, more OK? 99% of the time you can find the solution yourself.